# Horizontaly center a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have the following `LinearLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/about_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dev_buy_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dev_by_layout_height"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dev_buy_text"
            android:text="@string/dev_buy_text"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dev_by_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dev_by_value"
            android:text="@string/dev_by_value"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But it will not center itself, even after looking around for answers, they were of no use so far.

How may I do it?

Comment: Is this your root layout of Activity/Fragment?

Comment: I have added the root layout.

Comment: Hello in your linearlayout set width match_parent .

Answer (score 1):

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

This will work fine for you as parent layout is RelativeLayout

```
 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
 android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
```

And Remove These Lines :)

Answer (score 0):

It should work with [centerInParent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_centerInParent) property, as the main parent is a `RelativeLayout`.

Just do the following:

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

Comment: I do not wish to align the inner views but the layout itself.

Comment: I misunderstood, anyways the alignment is given based on the parent, in this case for RelativeLayout it would work with centerInParent, or you can play with android:layout_centerVertical="true" or android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" depending of what you want

Answer (score 0):

**There are two ways you can do it.**

First of all remove following lines from LinearLayout

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
```

**First would be add below line inside LinearLayout**

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

else

**Second would be write below line inside RelativeLayout**

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
```